# WCF and CipherSpecs (SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA)

Tags: wcf, ssl

I have a 3-tier application where server is Windows service and client connects to it using WCF. I need to provide some integration with 3-d party application. For this I plan to implement separate integration service and host it with WCF. But one of most important requirements is to use SSL v.3.0 CipherSuite - SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA to secure connection between server and 3-d party application.

My question is: how to configure my WCF service to enable SSL v.3.0 CipherSuite - SSL_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA?

Comment: I don't think this is can configured on .NET level. The only value you can change is if you want to use TLS or SSLv3 and that settings has global scope (`ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`). You should start with test client application and if it doesn't work ask on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/) what can be changed in your system to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Think test application can be helpful.

Comment: I tried this and .NET never uses this cipher. I even not be able to force IE or Firefox to use it. So you definitely need to start on Server Fault and ask if this configuration is even supported on Windows.